# GAMM factor-smooth interaction error

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model

I am using `gam` from the `mgcv` package to model the effects of climate on the size of small lakes. I have data from 70 lakes across 30 years. As change in lake area is non-linear over time, I have modeled `Year` as a smooth term:

`gam(Size ~ s(Year, Lake_ID, bs="fs") + Climate)`

where `Lake_ID` is a factor corresponding to each lake and `Climate`is the annual temperature and precipitation measurements. However, my PACF plot looks like:

[image]

Is my interpretation that this shows significant autocorrelation up to lag 6 correct? I have tried to fit the same model using `gamm` with an autocorrelation term.

`gamm(Size ~ s(Year, Lake_ID, bs="fs") + Climate, correlation = corAR1(form=~Year|Lake_ID)`

However, this gave the following error: `Error in matrix(0, size.cg[i], size.cg[i]) : object 'size.cg' not found`.

This error can be reproduced on a toy dataset below, which seems to only occur using the `bs="fs"` smooth:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(4,n=200,scale=2)
gamm1 <- gamm(y~s(f1,fac,bs="fs"), correlation = corAR1(form=~f1|fac),data=dat)
```

Is there some way to use the factor-smooth with corAR1 in gamm? Any ideas how to address the autocorrelation in the lake dataset using either `gam` or `gamm`?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a bug, but it occurred to me you could try the `t2()` specification for the random splines, which I just updated my answer with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, in principle and it seems like there might be some bugs in `mgcv::extract.lme.cov2`; some variables that need to be set (including `size.cg`, but others are needed) are not set but later are later referenced.

A key branch seems to be here:

```
if (n.levels >= start.level || n.corlevels >= start.level) {
    if (n.levels >= start.level) 
        Cgrps <- nlme::getGroups(b, level = start.level)
    else Cgrps <- grps
    Cind <- sort(as.numeric(Cgrps), index.return = TRUE)$ix
    rCind <- 1:n
    rCind[Cind] <- 1:n
    Clevel <- levels(Cgrps)
    n.cg <- length(Clevel)
    size.cg <- array(0, n.cg)
    for (i in 1:n.cg) size.cg[i] <- sum(Cgrps == Clevel[i])
}
else {
    n.cg <- 1
    Cind <- 1:n
}
```

This model/example is either not being captured by the statement in the `if()` or the `else` part needs to set more variables.

You should send an email to Simon Wood, at the address in `?bug.reports.mgcv` and provide him with the requested info and the reproducible example.

As an alternative, you might try the equivalent `t2()` construct:

```r
gamm1 <- gamm(y~ s(x1, fac, bs = c("cr", "re"), full = TRUE),
              correlation = corAR1(form = ~ x1 | fac),
              data = dat)
```

This doesn't work for the example (the model is over-specified) but might get you past the issue you encountered for your data.